# why can't i decode barcode by MultiFormatReader with follow code?

Tags: android, barcode, qr-code, zxing, code128

```
//MultiFormatReader
MultiFormatReader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
Map<DecodeHintType, Object> hints = new HashMap<>();
List<BarcodeFormat> formatList = new ArrayList<>();
hints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);
hints.put(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS,
    EnumSet.allOf(BarcodeFormat.class));
hints.put(DecodeHintType.PURE_BARCODE, Boolean.FALSE);
hints.put(DecodeHintType.ASSUME_GS1, Boolean.TRUE);

//encode
reader.decode(binaryBitmap, hints);
```

other code work perfect to decode **qrcode** ,what may be the problem?i want develop an app that can decode qrcode or barcode.

Comment: use this library https://github.com/zxing/zxing

Comment: my app is based on zxing already, is there anything different？@ karthickraja